# Angular 8: How to use formControlName with FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular8

How can I map `formControlName` to a specific `formArray` item?

I have no control over the server data and trying to create a form with a phone numbers array.

The form itself visually does not layout the phones side by side, and I want to be able to declare a phone's input control the same as I normally would with formGroup.

What I have so far is the below:

Controller:

```
const exampleData = {
                'name': 'John Doe',
                'phones': [
                    {
                        'type': 'home',
                        'number': '5555555'
                    },
                    {
                        'type': 'cell',
                        'number': '5555555'
                    }
                ]
            };

    this.form = this.fb.group({
         name:[],
         phones: this.fb.array([
             this.fb.group({
                 type: '',
                 number: []
             }),
             this.fb.group({
                 type: '',
                 number: []
             })
         ]),
     });

    this.form.patchValue(exampleData);
```

Template

```
<input type="text" formControlName="name">

<!--  This works but I need to loop -->
<div formArrayName="phones">
    <div *ngFor="let phone of form.get('phones').controls; let i = index">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <label>Type: </label><input formControlName="type"/>
            <label>Number: </label><input formControlName="number"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--  How can I point to a phone directly? -->
<input type="text" formControlName="point to type home's number...with helper function or something...">
```

Looking to see if this is even possible?

Comment: can you describe your problem clearly I don't get what i your problem so I can help 

Comment: @malbarmawi I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nukqvz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) about this question however once phone number is modified it is not updated and vice versa.

Comment: check my answer maybe will help 

Comment: @robert thanks for the demo  , I have managed to solve this problem

Comment: @robert, your example was what I was looking for (with '.at(1)', you can put in an answer.  I don't need to have two inputs pointing to the same form model value and updating, I only needed one. Thus, the loop in the template was just an example of what I knew. malbarmawi thanks for showing how to update the 2 form models and apologies if question was ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to get access to the formArray item:

```
  <div [formGroup]="form.get('phones').at(1)">
    <input type="text" formControlName="num">
  </div>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nukqvz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: this one a nice catch 

Answer (score 2):

I solve this by run `setValue` to that component again this why any input by the same form control will update ,this become like two way data binding when we use ngModel where the data flow to the instant and other controls.

this the method will create the formGroup

```
getPhoneGroup() {
    const form = this.fb.group({
      type: '',
      num: []
    });

    const elm = form.get('num');
    elm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      elm.setValue(val, { emitEvent: false })
    });

    return form;
  }
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhf7gd)

Comment: Great solution. Does these valueChanges subscriptions auto cleanup?

Comment: @robert no , I usually do unsubscribe but I haven't mentioned it here so the idea stay clear

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.